# Magento 2 Ui Component wysiwyg

Tags: magento, magento2

In Magento 2 how can we add the WYSIWYG editor with the text area field with the form ui component xml file? To add the text area i am using the following code in xml file.

```
<field name="detail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sample_shop</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Detail</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your ui component form xml file add the field like this.

```
 <field name="detail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sample_shop</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Detail</item>

                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">detail</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 3):

From Magento 2.2, below could work too. And it has better readability and usability.

```
    <field name="content" formElement="wysiwyg">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <label/>
            <dataScope>content</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Comment: This answer has the more up-to-date Magento xml parameters so is better than the accepted answer for anyone stumbling upon this more recently.